# NSIS: How to use the preporcessor or

Tags: boolean, nsis

I want something like this

```
!if (${Flag} == 5) || (${Flag} == 7)
     ...
!endif
```

But I get the error message `!if expects 1-4 parameters, got 7.
Usage: !if [!] value [(==,!=,<=,<,>,>=,&&,||) value2] [...]`. I tried  braces, but doesn't help.
The [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#if) mentions that `||` is allowed to use.

I found also the solution

```
!macro test
    ...
!macroend
!if ${Flag} == 5
     !insertmacro test
!else if ${Flag} == 7
     !insertmacro test
!endif
```

But this solution is very cumbersome and for what is then `||`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!if` does not support multiple expressions, it supports 1 or 3 parameters (not counting the `!` prefix). `||` is just a boolean expression (`OR`) where at least one of the parameters must evaluate to true:

```
!if ${Foo} || ${Bar}
     ...
!endif
```

Multiple expressions must be evaluated one by one:

```
!if ${Flag} = 5
     !insertmacro DoSomething
!else if ${Flag} = 7
     !insertmacro DoSomething
!endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the quotation marks. However the error message is not very helpful.

This is the solution

```
 !if "${Flag} == 5" || "${Flag} == 7"
     ...
 !endif
```